General method to graph curves
I am looking for some "general" method to make the graph of a 2 dimensional curve. What I mean by general is a clear path as the one can take with functions: looking for some points where it is not defined, taking limits in case they are needed, taking the derivative to see how it grows, taking the second derivative to check the convexity...
Why do I ask for something like this? Well, I am facing some curves like $f(x,y)=y(x^2+y^2)-x^2+y^2=0$ or $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3-3xy=0$ (Folium of Descartes). And I do not know if there is a clear way fo you, the reader, to graph those curves. I have seen some papers doing this: Looking for symmetry, taking partial derivatives and checking where do they vanish (singular points), checking of what class they are (They do not explain this part a lot so I do not know how to do it), looking for asymptotes (Again, there is not much explained so this part is not clear for me)...
Other papers give a parametrization and do a similar process, however, I see 2 big disadvantages here: you have to come with that parametrization and depending of which you chose you maybe get different singular points.
Would you be able to explain me some of you thoughts on this? Maybe with one of the 2 examples I gave? Thank you.

Minor point: what you're calling a “curve” is still a function, just a function of two variables. If $c$ is a regular value of $f$, then $f(x,y) = c$ is a curve.

Major point: I don't think what you're looking for exists.

@MatthewLeingang It was a typo, edited it

I do not see the need for being able to graph functions by hand, when you have access to computers. It is perhaps best to delegate the work. However, out of pure interest, if you do want to search for such a method, I think it would have to be finding the derivatives, and checking convexity, basically doing the typical "curve sketching" from calculus classes. This can be very challenging however as for complicated expressions such as this one there may not be analytical solutions available for the differential equations. which would make it very difficult to graph.

See the references listed under Classical Surveys of Curve Sketching in this Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange answer.

How general do you want your method to be? Can $f$ be any function? Continuous? Differentiable? Analytic? A polynomial?

@jjagmath I want the curve $f(x,y)=0$ be defined by $f(x,y)$ a polynomial in 2 variables.

You should specify that in the question, not just in a comment.

many curves are naturally defined in polar coordinates (say) and writing them in the form $f(x,y)=c$ is not that helpful. Best to find out about the curve, its history and motivation if possible.
